# How to searching in files for signs of a code injection

Tags: wordpress, code-injection

Hi the website of a friend was hacked.
Many files have gotten code injections. His programmer deleted all these.

Now the situation is, that the site (wordpress with shop plugin) is still running realy slow sometimes. Sometimes it goes fast.

Now after searching the web for: "troubleshooting code injections", "find code injections" and stuff like that, I have no idea to troubleshoot the problem, because his programmer has no local backup and changed all files so I cant look for recently changed files at all.

What would be the way of choice to get the problem?

Comment: Either roll back or start again. If you miss something your website could be compromised again. Also try to find out __how__ the site was hacked so you can apply a security patch if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Possible Solution or Suggestions:

[Use these very famous virus scanning and detecting website](https://www.virustotal.com/) 
By using above site you will come to know if virus still exist or not.

Suggestions:

As you said you are using wordpress so it will be very easy to detect virus.how?

Use following security plugins for scanning core files.

- All In One WP Security & Firewall
- wordfence

Lastly 
To hacker's or malware lives in follow important files of wordpress
Check all theme files specially

```
header.php
footer.php
index.php ( mostly infected )
```

also do a upgrade of wordpress so it will make sure that core files are not modified.

thanks
hope it helps